# How can I prevent sculpt deformation?

Tags: subdivision-surface, sculpt

This is my first sculpt and I want to ask 2 question, how i can prevent the formation of these deformations? Is there an option to set for fix that problem?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSC9D.jpg

Comment: Include your mages directly into the question body please and make them bigger so that it's clear what is shown. Also avoid any unnecessary symbols in the title and question body

Comment: hard to tell what it is, maybe you don't have enough geometry and you should use Dyntopo?